# Plot in child (Matlab)

Tags: matlab

Can someone please tell me how does the last plot command work in following script?

```
close all;
s=tf('s');
sys1 = 5/(s+5);
sys2=exp(-1*s);
G=ss(sys1)*ss(sys2);
opts = bodeoptions('cstprefs');
opts.Grid= 'ON';
% create a figure and get the handle of the figure
figHnd = figure;
bode(G,opts)
% get and display the children handles of the figure
childrenHnd =get(figHnd, 'Children');
% select magnitude plot and plot a line
axes(childrenHnd(3));
hold on;
plot([1 1], [-20 20], 'r')
hold off;
```

I am trying to add a horizontal line for cut-off frequency to my Bode plot (magnitude diagram) but I can't figure out how to do that. The current code adds a vertical line for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is about the line

```
plot([1 1], [-20 20], 'r')
```

which is a simple plot command. In general, you use

```
plot(x,y)
```

here it is the same: the `x`-vector is `[1, 1]` and the `y`-vector is `[-20, 20]`. So you draw a line from the point `(1,-20)` to `(1,20)`. The last part (`r`) only specifies the color, i.e. red. This is exactly what you can see in the bode plot.

To create a horizontal line e.g. from `(10^-1, -20)` to `(10^0, -20)` you can similarily draw

```
plot([10^-1, 10^0], [-20, -20], 'r');
```

(don't forget to put it within `hold on; ... hold off;`, so the bode plot isn't erased.

Comment: Much more in depth than the other answer. +1.

Answer (score 0):

change the last plot code similar to this:

```
plot([1 10], [-20 -20], 'r')
```

Refer [plot](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) and work on some examples to get an idea of how it works.